# Swift - Create a custom push segue

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a segue that moves from left to right with animation. I need help on the custom segue code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question myself.

When I was creating by segue, I had to make it `"custom"` instead of `"show"`.
Then, I had to create a new file that controlled my custom segue(a `UIStoryBoardSegue` file) . Then I added this code to that file:

```
override func perform() {
        var firstVCView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
        var secondVCView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

        // Get the screen width and height.
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
        secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth, 0.0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

        // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

        // Animate the transition.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in

                firstVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVCView.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0)
                secondVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondVCView.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0)

            }) { (Finished) -> Void in
                self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController,
                    animated: false,
                    completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Thanks anyways Cole.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is very broad. I suggest you check out [Spring](https://github.com/MengTo/Spring) which is a very good animation library. Play around with the example project. One of them is actually a side-to-side movement that you can customize. That's as detailed as I can go without any context.